Strapi blank screen issue on admin dashboard
Strapi admin dashboard shows blank white screen on content manager while on specific collection.
Everything was working fine in v4.16.2. When we upgrade to 4.17.0 or later, the issue occurs.
Steps to reproduce -
create a collection type with a repeatable component. (collection 1)
create two more collections with out a component (only fields) (collection 2 & 3)
Add data in collection 3.
Go to content manager in admin dashboard. Open collection 1, works fine as expected (to be able to add content, save and publish)
Click on collection 2( without any data), then click on collection 1, works fine as expected (to be able to add content, save and publish)
Click on collection 3(with data), then click on collection 1, now the white screen happens.
checked the console log, getting an issue of error reading length of undefined.
Steps tried to resolve -
changed to a new db.
removed the newly added plugins and a fresh install.
deleted the collection 1 and created a same collection.
Started using yarn instead of npm.
4.16.2 works fine and stable. Any version later doesn’t work. (4.17.0 - latest)
Note:- SuperAdmins can refresh to make it work but refreshing everytime makes it cumbersome and not usable for production.
Non Super Admins cannot even check other collection types, the screen is just blank for them.
Admin dashboard should be working and users should be able to add content in collections.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
